# Typescript: after the transpilation, wrong retun type

Tags: typescript

Why my index.ts

```
export const isNullOrUndefined = (value: any): value is null | undefined => {
  return value === null || value === undefined;
};
```

is transpiled into index.d.ts (only value is null)

```
export declare const isNullOrUndefined: (value: any) => value is null;
```

instead of (value is null | undefined)

```
export declare const isNullOrUndefined: (value: any) => value is null | undefined;
```

this is the tsconfig file on typescript 4.9.5

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": false,
    "target": "es2019",
    "outDir": "build",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "traceResolution": false,
    "listEmittedFiles": false,
    "listFiles": false,
    "pretty": true,
    "lib": ["es2019", "dom"],
    "types": ["node"],
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/**"],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you don't have [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) enabled. From the option's documentation:

> When `strictNullChecks` is `false`, `null` and `undefined` are effectively ignored by the language. This can lead to unexpected errors at runtime.
>
> When `strictNullChecks` is `true`, `null` and `undefined` have their own distinct types and you’ll get a type error if you try to use them where a concrete value is expected.

Add at least:

```
"strictNullChecks": true,
```

to your `tsconfig.json` (although I'd recommend [all of the `strict` flags](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict), via `"strict": true`).